# Regular expression for 6-10 alphanumeric chars with at least 1 alphabetic char

Tags: regex

I have been asked to do a password validation regular expression by a client, but I can't get it to work.

The specifications are:

- 6-10 characters long
- only a-z, A-Z, 0-9
- not completely from digits (eg. at least 1 a-z or A-Z char)

I've come up with this so far:  `d*[a-zA-Z]([A-Za-z0-9])\\w{6,10}`

Comment: @ThiefMaster As much as I respect you as a moderator, your comment does not provide any kind of help to the actual question. This requirement comes from a client and although I know this is not a good requirement, I am not in position to change the client's mind.

Comment: Why regex? A lot of password validation requirements are better expressed in a short amount of code. (For example, in Python, you'd do `6 <= len(pw) <= 10 and pw.isalnum() and any(c.isalpha() for c in pw)`.

Comment: is digit(s) obligatory?

Comment: Just saying that it might be useful to tell your client to re-consider the requirement. That's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[A-Za-z0-9]{6,10}$` should work for you.

Comment: @nneonneo, I'm sorry, but I have to disagree with you.  A good regex allow you to do several tests at once, in only one pass over the whole string.  Checking for length forces to do one pass over the whole string.  All the tests you have shown require a pass through the password each.  You can do things like checking for a CRC, checking for strings multple of 3 and length checks with just one regex at once.  So why to select your approach.  Your algorithm is going to be hidden from the user to astonish him. So why not select the most effective one?

Comment: Regexes don't have to be fast or even remotely efficient. It's quite easy to write a regex that exhibits pathological behaviour, and understanding and avoiding those cases is much harder than with plain code. It's also easier to debug, understand, maintain and read plain code than regex. Regexes have their place - I'm not disputing that - but there are many situations where plain code is just the simpler approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a candidate regex

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d*)([a-zA-Z]{6,10}|[a-zA-Z\d]{6,10})$
```

that allows following characters:

```
 [a-zA-Z]       // only letters
 [a-zA-Z\d]     // or letters and digits
 {6,10}         // in qty 6-10
```

followed by

```
 (?=.*[a-zA-Z]) // letters and
 (?=.*\d*)      // digit in qty zero and more
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cS8jE0/5)

Comment: This did work, only thing that needed to be added was A-Z for uppercase characters. I've edited your answer to reflect that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*a-zA-Z)[A-Za-z\d]{6,10}$
```

should get you what you need

- ^ assert position at start of the string
- (?=.*[A-Za-z]) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
  -.* matches any character (except newline)

  - Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
  - [A-Za-z] match a single character present in the list below
  - A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
  - a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
- (?=.*[a-zA-Z]) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched

  - Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
  - [a-zA-Z] match a single character present in the list below

    - a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case insensitive)
    - A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case insensitive)
- [A-Za-z\d]{6,10} match a single character present in the list below

  - Quantifier: {6,10} Between 6 and 10 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
  - A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
  - a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
  - \d match a digit [0-9]
- $ assert position at end of the string

Comment: I've tested your regex multiple times and it didn't work for all cases. @MaxZoom had the correct answer.

Comment: What cases are those? I am curious